Gerrit filter to show commits created before 2 days
I want to create a gerrit filter that will show all commits created (1st patchset) before 2 days from now.
or even get a notification mail when a commit is under review for more than 2 days.
Is it possible to do? and how?
  <gerrit created 2 days before>
i didn't try anything - don't know how

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
